# Is WPF toolkit compatible with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# program and I need to add a chart to it. I have downloaded WPF Toolkit and ran the installer. But the tools aren't appearing in my toolbox in design view.

I can't find any good guide on setting up WPF Tooking on the net, even the WPF Toolkit webpage doesn't have any documentation which is a bit of a joke. So can anyone tell me how to get WPF Toolkit working with VS2012?

Or if anyone has suggestions on some other free charting library that can do the job and has some documentation I would love to here them.

Comment: It seems to me that adding simply references to the assemblies has to be enough.

Comment: There is a NuGet package with that name but try it out first. Doesn't look complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the installer was created, but if it fails to register Toolbox items, you can manually create them. Even some commercial control vendors suggest that when their installer fails, such as

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/installation-adding-to-vs-2010-toolbox-wpf.html

You might also provide a bug report to WPF Toolkit project.